Logarithm of a $p$-group in $\mathrm{GL}_n(p)$
$\def\GL{\operatorname{GL}}\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}\def\FF{\mathbb{F}}\def\Id{\mathrm{Id}}\def\fu{\mathfrak{u}}$Let $p$ be prime, let $n<p$, let $U_n(\FF_p)$ be the group of $n \times n$ upper triangular matrices with $1$'s on the diagonal, and let $\fu_n(\FF_p)$ be the $\FF_p$-Lie algebra of $n \times n$ upper triangular matrices with $0$'s on the diagonal. Then we have mutually inverse bijections
$$ \exp : \fu_n(\FF_p) \to U_n(\FF_p) \quad \text{and} \quad \log : U_n(\FF_p) \to \fu_n(\FF_p)$$
given by the usual power series. These power series are actually polynomials since the matrices involved are nilpotent, and we never divide by $p$ since $n<p$.
Question: Suppose that $G$ is a subgroup of $U_n(\FF_p)$. Is $\log(G)$ a Lie-subalgebra of $\fu_n(\FF_p)$?
Motivation:  See here for a related question where the answer turned out to be "no". I was motivated by this vexing question, but I no longer claim my approach there is useful. I wanted to turn the question of embedding groups into a question of embedding Lie algebras, and thus turn it into the question of effective bounds in Ado's theorem. In particular, I believed that I had a family of $2$-step nilpotent Lie algebras whose smallest faithful representation had dimension $\Omega(n^2)$. But, according to this survey on effective versions of Ado, for nilpotence degree $\leq 3$, $n+1$ always suffices.
Remark: The hard part is showing that $\log(G)$ is closed
under addition. If so, I'm pretty sure I can show that it's closed under Lie bracket. I'll upload the details of this in the unlikely case that someone can do addition but not Lie bracket.

In other words, on $\mathfrak{u}_n(F_p)$ you have both the Lie algebra and group law (pullback of the group law by exp). There is a way to formulate the Lie algebras laws (sum and bracket) in terms of the group law, involving rational powers. These are Lazard formulas. If I'm correct with your conditions $p$ won't appear in denominators, and hence the answer to your question is positive. I'll double check.

The reference is https://doi.org/10.24033/asens.1021 (Lazard 1954), about "inversion of Hausdorff's formula". It's not obvious to read the result, but I'm pretty sure it's covered.

@YCor Ah, thanks! I read French very slowly, so it will take me a while to work through Lazard, but I found http://www.numdam.org/item/10.1007/s10240-016-0087-3.pdf , and Theorem 5.C.1 is clearly relevant. The only question is whether the integers $q_s$ and $q'_s$ in that theorem are divisible by $p$.

Indeed, we didn't have to care on denominators when we wrote this.
